# Best approximation of piecewise constant function by Lipschitz functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, na.numerical-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control, approximation-theory

Let $f=\sum_{n=1}^N k_n I_{E_n}$ where $E_n$ are Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $k_n\in \mathbb{R}^m$ with non-negative entries, and let $\mu$ be a finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  What is the best rate of approximation, in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ of $f$ by Lipschitz functions?  That is, given any positive integer $n$ and some $L>0$, what order is:
$$
\inf_{g \in Lip(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m); Lip(g)\leq L}\,\int_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} \|g(x)-f(x)\|d\mu(x)?
$$

Comment: The infimum is 0 because the Lip functions are dense in $L^1$. Maybe you mean the best approximation by Lipschitz functions *with a given Lipschitz constant*?

Comment: Right good point; I updated the post.

Comment: I guess, even in general for $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$, it may be given in terms of  the "modulus of $L^1$-continuity" of $f$, that is 
$\omega(\delta):=\sup_{\|h\|\le\delta}\|f-f_h\|_1,$
where $f_h(x):=f(x-h)$.

Comment: @Pietro I also figured something like this; but wouldn't we need $f$ to belong to a Sobolev class?

Comment: I don't think so; the problem you posed is meaningful even for $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$, that is to estimate the point-set distance
$$d(k):=\rm{dist}\big(f, \rm{Lip_k}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)\big),$$
and its decay for $k\to+\infty$.

Comment: Interesting!  Would you happen to know of a reference where I can read into this specifically?